# Clojure threading macro

Tags: clojure

I'm not sure this is the best place to post, but why doesn't 2) work? Doesn't the threading macro pass the result of seq into `(map str)`?

```
;; 1
(map str (seq (str (* 8 8)))) -> ("6" "4")

;; 2
(defn a [x y]
  (-> (* x y)
      str
      seq
      (map str)))


(a 8 8) -> Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.core$str
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the [thread-first](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E) macro, which inserts each form as the second item of the next, like this:

```
(-> (* x y) str seq (map str))
(-> (str (* x y)) seq (map str))
(-> (seq (str (* x y))) (map str))
(map (seq (str (* x y))) str)
```

What you want is the [thread-last](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) macro:

```
(defn a [x y]
  (->> (* x y) str seq (map str)))

(a 8 8) ;=> ("6" "4")
```

Answer (score 7):

as Elogent points out the macro is putting the arguments in the wrong place. In general when working with macros (and especially writing them) it helps to know about `macroexpand-1` and combine it with `clojure.pprint/pprint` to get a clear view of what is actually running:

```
user> (clojure.pprint/pprint
       (macroexpand-1
        '(-> (* x y)
             str
             seq
             (map str))))
(map (seq (str (* x y))) str)
nil
```

Which we can see doesn't quite look right. So next we fiddle with it until it expands to what we expect:

```
user> (clojure.pprint/pprint
       (macroexpand-1
        '(->> (* x y)
              str
              seq
              (map str))))
(map str (seq (str (* x y))))
nil
```

There are a variety of threading macros to help with situations like this, especially `as->` which lets you give an explicit name to the threaded value when you need to thread functions that alternate using the first and last argument for the important input:

```
user> (as-> (* 7 42) x
        (str x)
        (seq x)
        (map str x))
("2" "9" "4")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative that is good to know (it's read from right to left):

```
(defn a [x y]
  ((comp (partial map str) seq str *)
    x y))
```

This might be useful in contexts where you want to separate the transformations to apply, from the data they're applied to (I would welcome criticism on the subject ).

Comment: Your intention is good, but since you're already combining the transformation and the data into the `a` function, you don't really gain anything from that approach here.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider using the `it->` threading form from [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo), which is designed to avoid thread-first vs thread-last worries.  Consider this code:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:use tupelo.core))

(defn a [x y]
  (it-> (* x y)
      (str it)
      (seq it)
      (map str it)))

(spyx (a 8 8))

(defn -main [] )
```

Which produces:

```
(a 8 8) => ("6" "4")
```

The `it->` macro uses the placeholder `it` to explicitly choose where to place the result of each successive form. This is an easy way to simplify code and avoid this type of error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like a pretty sweet library.